What diode size for connecting two AC to DC power supplies in series
I would love to connect two power supplies together in series.  They are both Meanwell UHP-500-12 power supplies to get 1000 watts at 24 volts (the Meanwell UHP-1000-24 only generates 700 watts on 120 volt AC in USA). The datasheet is https://www.meanwellusa.com/productPdf.aspx?i=832#1
I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sAUiarvu88
Which includes this diagram:

Unfortunately, I cannot find more information on recommended diodes (circled in yellow).  What type of diode should I be looking for?  Thank you in advance!  :)

The diodes are there to prevent one supply from applying reverse voltage to the output of the other supply if they do not turn on at the same time. Therefore, the diodes should be sized for the full current of one supply (average rectified current).  I would play it safe and select a reverse voltage in excess of both supplies in series.

@Jared Carter, Keep in mind - series connection may double the voltage but the current will stay at single PS rate.
